# MySQL Query Optimization Group By with Max

Tags: database, database-design, group-by, query-optimization, groupwise-maximum

Trying to optimise MySQL query which uses Group by with Max. Trying to get latest updated frames which were active before any past date.

**Audit Frame Table Structure:**

```
id bigint pk AI
frame_id bigint fk
name VARCHAR(50)
active int
createdOn DATETIME
updatedOn DATETIME
deletedOn DATETIME
```

id, frame_id and updatedOn have individual indexes..

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id1 
  FROM audit_frame_master 
 WHERE updatedOn <='2019-03-25 21:00:00' 
   AND active=1 
   AND deletedOn IS NULL 
 GROUP 
    BY frame_id
```

**Performance:**

Table has around 1M rows. It takes average 4 seconds to perform.. Is there any way to optimise above query?

Below is the EXPLAIN statement for the same.
[image]

Comment: What is your cluster index column?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos: id is the cluster index column.

Comment: why do you need both `AND active=1 
   AND deletedOn IS NULL` ? can `AND active=1` be enough?

Comment: Basically I want active list of frames for particular date which were not deleted.

Comment: But could Active frames be deleted? usually when delete record should get `active = 0` or if not - then why do you need `active=1` to check?

Comment: @Alex: Obviously when a row is logically deleted, its `deletedOn` is set and nothing else. You can still see what the row looked like when it got deleted, e.g. whether it was active then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks fine. All you can do is provide an appropriate index. That would be an index on the columns in the `WHERE` clause at least. Start with the most restrictive column. So,

- how many rows match `active = 1`?
- how many rows match `deletedOn IS NULL`?
- how many rows match `updatedOn <= timestamp '2019-03-25 21:00:00'`?

Pick the one that gets the least number of rows. Say it's `active`, then `updatedOn`, then `deletedOn`. This gives you:

```
create index idx on audit_frame_master(active, updatedOn, deletedOn);
```

As you want to group by `frame_id` then and then find the maximum `id`, you can add those in this order:

```
create index idx on audit_frame_master(active, updatedOn, deletedOn, frame_id, id);
```

This is a covering index. If the DBMS uses it, it doesn't even have to access the table.

The DBMS may or may not use this index. It's just an offer. If the DBMS thinks it will be too much work to go through an index rather then simply read the table sequentially, then it won't use it. Just try.

Comment: I added those indexes and seems like there is an improvement in the performance but still that is not that quick.. Is it due to updatedOn and deletedOn are DateTime and taking more calculation time?

Comment: No, that shouldn't matter. It's just a lot of work to do. How many rows do you get with the separate conditions, how many with the combined one? How many different  frames are in the table, how many in your result?

Comment: Please see my edited question.. I have attached explain statement.

Comment: I don't know how to read MySQL explain plans. Do I see it correctly that the `WHERE` clause keeps more than 10% of the table's rows? Then the DBMS doesn't benefit much from the index. It's just a lot of data to sort and aggregate.

Comment: Yes it might have more than 10% of the table's rows in some cases.. Do you suggest any specific DB table change in that case?

Comment: No. Everything looks fine to me. It's just a query that takes some time to execute. Such queries exist.

Comment: Though your index solution one for where and one overall reduce execution time to 50% so I think rest of the time is just a sort and aggregate.

Comment: I am closing this thread by accepting this answer as this was giving more decline in execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following composite index: `(frame_id, active, deletedOn, updatedOn, id)` and report how it performs.

Comment: Not much more visual improvement.. @Willem

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want

```
 SELECT frame_id, MAX(id)
```

instead of

```
 SELECT           MAX(id)
```

??

Probably this it the optimal index.  Note how it lists the `WHERE` columns first, on the assumption that filtering is more important than grouping:

```
INDEX(active, deletedOn,   -- in either order
      updatedOn)
```

Tacking on `frame_id, id` (in either order, but at the end) would turn it into a "covering" index, thereby gaining a little more speed.